# Returning value instead of promise in useEffect in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, es6-promise

I have the following code,

```
let currencyValues = [];

const retrieveCurrencyPairs = async (pair) => {
    const r = await fetch(pair.url);
    const rParsed = await r.json();
    let newCurrencyValue = { currency: pair.countries, value: rParsed };
    return newCurrencyValue;
};

useEffect(() => {
    currencyValues = currencyPairs.map(retrieveCurrencyPairs);
    console.log(currencyValues);
}, []);
```

and the following expectations:

- On page load, the `useEffect` triggers the function inside of the map()
- For each value of the array, the `retrieveCurrencyPairs()` is triggered and awaits for the result, which is then returned
- The `currencyValues` array is the filled with the 3 new objects

Unfortunately the function is returning promises, instead of the objects.

Any tip on how to return the objects instead?

Comment: async functions always return promises even implicitly. You need either await  the `currency.Pairs.map(retrieveCurrencyPairs)` either `.then` it

Comment: async functions _always_ return promises. You could `Promise.all(currencyPairs.map(retrieveCurrencyPairs)).then( results => ... )`.

Comment: @ray this works, if u add it as answer I will mark it as correct!

Comment: @EricMitjans Answer added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

async functions *always* return promises. You could do this instead:

```js
Promise.all(currencyPairs.map(retrieveCurrencyPairs))
  .then( results => ... )
```

[Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) has the additional benefit of running them all in parallel instead of sequentially.

You might consider [Promise.allSettled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) if you want to deal with individual failures/rejections without rejecting the whole list.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use `Promise.all` in order to properly handle multiple promises

```
useEffect(() => {
    (async()=>{
        const results = await Promise.all(currencyPairs.map(retrieveCurrencyPairs))
        console.log(results );
    })()
}, []);
```

OR

```
useEffect(() => {
   const results = Promise.all(currencyPairs.map(retrieveCurrencyPairs)).then(results => console.log(results));     
}, []);
```

To learn more about `Promise.all` or To learn more about `Promise.allSettled` use MDN

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  useEffect(() => {
    (async()=>{
        currencyValues = await currencyPairs.map(retrieveCurrencyPairs);
        console.log(currencyValues);
    })()
    }, []);
```

Comment: Still returning promises!

Comment: can you please share your output pic here

Answer (score 0):

async functions always return promises even implicitly. You need to either await the `currency.Pairs.map(retrieveCurrencyPairs)` either `.then` it

Since a `Promise.all` answer is already posted and is a good practice to stick with one approach, here is the alternative with `await`

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getCurrencyValues = async ()=>{
    const currencyValues = await currencyPairs.map(retrieveCurrencyPairs);
    return currencyValues
    }
    console.log(getCurrencyValues());

}, []);
```